# sjplot plot_model with own color palette

Tags: r, colors, sjplot, multilevel-analysis

I apologize if this is a very basic question, but I'm having trouble defining colors when using plot_model in sjplot. As an example, I have run a simple multilevel regression model where 76 participants represent clusters. Each participant responded to a bunch of questions 16 times over the course of 4 days. The model goes

```
m<-lmer(happy ~ soc_smc + (soc_smc | id), data=data)
```

I want to plot the random slopes with plot_model:

```
p<-plot_model(m, type="pred", terms=c("soc_smc", "id"), pred.type="re", ci.lvl = NA)
```

Which works nicely, however sjplot base color palettes apparently have max 9 colors and I get 9 colored slopes and 67 grey ones.

I tried to create and use my own palette, e.g.

```
c1<-colors(distinct=T)
mycols<-sample(c1, 76)
p<-plot_model(m, type="pred", terms=c("soc_smc", "id"), pred.type="re", ci.lvl = NA, colors = "mycols")
```

However, I get the error "Error: Unknown colour name: mycols"
Same with colorspace

```
library(colorspace)
mycols<-qualitative_hcl(76)
p<-plot_model(m, type="pred", terms=c("soc_smc", "id"), pred.type="re", ci.lvl = NA, colors = "mycols")
```

Again plot_model says Error: "Unknown colour name: mycols"

I'm very inexperienced in creating color palettes so maybe I'm doing something wrong there, but why plot_model doesn't seem to recognize the palette object? Or am I reading the error wrong?

I don't actually need 76 *distinctive* colors (and that would be impossible too), however I'd like to get some color for every slope, and most importantly to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass you color palette to the `colors` argument without quotes.

Using one of the default examples from `sjPlot::plot_model`:

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(colorspace)

mycols <- qualitative_hcl(76)

m <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)

plot_model(m,
  type = "pred", terms = c("Days", "Subject"),
  pred.type = "re", ci.lvl = NA, colors = mycols
)
```

[image]

Comment: OMG I can't believe I didn't try that! Thank you so much!

Comment: I have a sjplot, too, but only need 3 colours, and want them to be in hexadecimal code - and you can just enter your prefered hexcodes in the parenthesis ie. color = c ("#1...", "#12..","#123.")